# UWP Commandbar to right side

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, commandbar

I want to move the `CommandBar` to the right side and let the AppBarButtons flow from top to down. In other words I want to rotate the `CommandBar` by 90 degrees from top to the right side of the Page

How can I achieve that?

J.

Answer (score 4):

CommandBar does not have a vertical orientation mode, so you cannot do this.  You could rotate it 90 degrees using

```
<CommandBar.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="90" />
</CommandBar.RenderTransform>
```

but the buttons would be rotated as well.  You should consider a different control, like a SplitView.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that easily, because `CommandBar` is built for horizontal mode by default (including the expansion animations, flyout behavior, etc.). With higher effort you could be able to modify the default template to support this. Also, you can use `AppBarButton` controls anywhere, not just in `CommandBar`. My suggestion would be to use something like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
   <AppBarButton ... />
   <AppBarButton ... />
   <AppBarButton ... />
<StackPanel>
```

You could use the `AppBarButton`'s `LabelPosition` property set to `Collapsed` to hide the labels for a cleaner experience.

Comment: But how can I adjust the StackPanel to the size of the AppBarButtons? The StackPanel is too big and doesn't look great

Comment: The problem is not in the `StackPanel` but rather in the default paddings the `AppBarButtons` have. You will have to modfiy the `AppBarButton` template to remove that padding.